# How to set the size and position of an image?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-layout, android-imageview

I am trying to set the size and position of an image (image2) on the screen so that it is in the same position and size relative to the background image (image1) it is on no matter the screen size. To do this, I try to alter the layout parameters of image2 in my `onCreate` method of my `Activity` class:

```
    public class Game_main extends Activity{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);



        ImageView image2= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.seed1);
        ImageView image1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.board_rev1);


        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlGame);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((image1.getWidth())/4, (image2.getHeight())/4);
        params.leftMargin = (image1.getWidth())/2;
        params.topMargin = (image1.getHeight())/4;
        rl.addView(image2, params);
        setContentView(R.layout.gamerev);


}


}
```

But when my app goes to this activity, I get an error that says the application has stopped unexpectedly. Then I have to force close the app. Why would this happen? Is there something I am missing? or is there a better way to do this?

The error in the logcat is:

E/AndroidRuntime(  296): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity Co
mponentInfo{com.soft.tobi/com.soft.tobi.Game_main}: java.lang.NullPointerExc
eption

But I dont see why anything would be null because all the ids exist in my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/rlGame"
  >
    <ImageView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/board_rev1" android:src="@drawable/board_rev1"></ImageView>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/seed1" android:src="@drawable/seed1" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:layout_height="200dp" android:layout_marginTop="165dp" android:layout_width="200dp" android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"></ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: where are you doing this? (if in onCreate it won't work since getWidth will return zero).  What is the error in the logcat?  you haven't provided enough info to help you.

Comment: I am doing this in OnCreate. How can I get the logcat? I tried running $adb logcat  as in: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html but it didn't work. Is there any other information you need?

Comment: I have updated my question to include all the necessary information

Answer (score 0):

Did you put a try catch block and try to debug it ? It seems to be something returns null..

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is size of imageview

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((image1.getWidth())/4, (image2.getHeight())/4);
```

maybe it return 0 so this problem is occur..try it