# How to place multiple ImageViews dynamically in Relative Layout Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this loop code to create multiple imageView:

```
for (int i = 0; i != noOfImage; i++) {
                image[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img);
        }
```

The problem is the placement of the image, I want it to be dynamical create at different location.

I am trying to do something like this whereby the circle is place randomly: 
[image]

Comment: what you mean 'different location'?

Comment: may be this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497007/android-relativelayout-how-to-position

Comment: This might help, [setting size and position of the image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905848/how-to-set-the-size-and-position-of-an-image)

Comment: can i see whole code? with your main layout?? do you have the location point of every place where you are going to place the imageview dynamically ??